# Test Environment and back to Production via SSH

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ssh

I'm trying to understand how to put online my Test Finished Magento and to have a Test folder where to continue to make customization to put on the store.

I don't find a guide that explain me, initially if I need to stop some counter or something similar. The point is, I put my store online, orders arrives, customers growns, and I'm steel modifying my site in the test environment. When It's ready, I want to update the live site. How can i do that without loosing customers and orders? Can you link me a guide or can you give me a procedure to follow. Best if it is in SSH. I think may be more fast to repeat in the future.

I think the same procedure I can repeat if some upgrades are released so if I update my test environment than I can copy with the same procedure, the new updated magento on the old live site, right?

Looking for guidance.Thank you!

Comment: You can create copy of your store say beta and you can use git or manually put update from beta to live what change you do.

Comment: can you be more specific what you mean with git? It's a paring system? Elsewhere, if I put update from beta to live, I don't loose the new customers and orders put in the development time?

Comment: Bitbucket.org (git) it versioning system , or for manually update only code from beta to live not database

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can approach this and they depend on various factors such as the production /dev enviroments you are using or have available. In short though it is important to have the same (or as similar as is possible) enviroment for both - same versions of **web server, magento, PHP +modules, MySQL** or **other DB** etc.

One way to approach it is to have production online `www.yourdomain.com` and to create you development server by doing a full copy of the magento root folder **(you dont need /var folder in this )** and a full copy of your database.  Set this up to be accessed as `dev.yourdomain.com.`

> Important :

To get this to work you would need to change the settings in the database table `core_config_data` that are set to `www.yourdomain.com` to `dev.yourdomain.com` and also change the the file `/app/etc/local.xml` to edit the database connection values to point to your development database.

It can take a bit of troubleshooting to get working but usually any issues are related to cache so keep deleting **/var/cache folder** to clear it out , also clear you browsers cache or even better use **incognito mode /private browsing**. You can also try adding random parameters add the end of the url like `dev.yourdomain.com?random123` you are testing to force you browser to see it as a different page and to not load from browser cache.

You should also not it is a good idea to then use **separate browsers**, say **chrome and firefox**, to access the live & dev admins and for site testing because using the same browser can cause confusion due to cookies and session issues.

Another possible approach is as above but to have the development environment on your local PC, leaving everything set up as `www.yourdomain.com` and to use a HOSTS file switcher application (or manunally change hosts files but that gets annoying very quickly) to point www.yourdomain.com to 127.0.0.1 localhost.

Comment: ok this is what I was yet thinking to do. Actually I've still no live installation, so my url is www.mydomain.com/Test. I was thinking to mantain this for the Test and the standard domain for the live. My question was more on how to update the live site after I will make more customization. So my thinking was to finish all modifications and add. Then to put the live on maintenance, backup customers and orders, then load on the test installation. Then reload the test installation on the live one.

Comment: But I need to know how to make this db pairing, which tables to take and overall if this approach can have some problems that I don't see.

Comment: I think it very much depends on what changes you make really - yes of course backing up is a good idea but you dont always need to backup the DB. 
Im not too sure having a parellel installation of magento on the same server would be too good an idea though as it would effect performance

Comment: Ok i Will test this but now I'm not asking this but how to sync only customers and order and all linked data

Comment: for a development server , im not sure why you would need to synch customers and orders but to synch the DBs you can manually do a data export from live and then import back into dev db. Or , setting up some kind of mysql replication. Depending on what you are doing exactly (for example just changes to css and design)  you can also just have both dev and live magento installations pointing to the same DB but obviiously if your doing anything that makes DB changes then thats not a good idea

Comment: My needs for updating customers and orders in the dev is  because I need to add more products and change layout of pages. So the short way for me is to make also deep modifications to the dev then when it's ready, instead of bring them to the live with several problems, the short way is to bring customers and orders to the dev and then transfer all the dev folder and db to the live. I think is the short way right?

Comment: So I need to know which are the tables to export for this purpose.  And if there's a guide to know how copy the contents of those tables with a query, to run it several times to not lose time to export manually each time those tables. I think I will need a query that delete all the tables content on the dev db and load the content of live tables on it.

Comment: to be honest your are going to find it very difficult to find that exact information in order to export just orders, customer etc from the tables - the way its setup us is pretty complicated. You might want to look into using the the import/export function and dataflow profiles and run them by cron - bit of a learning curve there though. MySql replication would be easiest and if you can doing it through AWS would probably be quite easy to acheive what you want